# SQL SELECT - Return new columns populated with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables in a database as follows (the simplified versions):

**ProductDescriptions**

```
| ProductId | CategoryId | Url          | Image       | Description |
|-----------|------------|--------------|-------------|-------------|
| product01 | 1          | /page01.html | image01.jpg | Lorem ipsum |
| product02 | 1          | /page02.html | image02.jpg | Lorem ipsum |
| product03 | 2          | /page03.html | image03.jpg | Lorem ipsum |
```

**ProductAttributes**

```
| ProductId | Attribute   | Value  |
|-----------|-------------|--------|
| product01 | Inch/Metric | Metric |
| product01 | Weight      | 2lb    |
| product01 | Size        | 8in    |
| product02 | Inch/Metric | Inch   |
| product02 | Weight      | 1lb    |
| product02 | Size        | 5in    |
etc...
```

How can I select all the rows in `ProductDescriptions` with a `CategoryId` of `01`, but also return the associated attributes in the second table as new columns?  The column names can be defined manually.  The result would look something like this:

**Desired Result**

```
| ProductId | CategoryId | Url          | Image       | Description | Inch/Metric | Weight | Size |
|-----------|------------|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|--------|------|
| product01 | 01         | /page01.html | image01.jpg | Lorem Ipsum | Metric      | 2lb    | 8in  |
| product02 | 01         | /page02.html | image02.jpg | Lorem Ipsum | Inch        | 1lb    | 5in  |
```

I've tried using various forms of `JOIN`, but those are creating extra records in my result.  I want to attach all the product attributes to a single record in my query.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to use a PIVOT to convert rows into columns. The syntax will vary depending upon the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
with t1 as (
select *
from ProductAttributes as pa
PIVOT (max(value) FOR Attribute in ([Inch/Metric], Weight, Size)) as P
) 
select pd.ProductId, CategoryId, Url, Image, Description, [Inch/Metric], Weight, Size 
from ProductDescriptions as pd
inner join t1 
on pd.ProductId = t1.ProductId
where CategoryId = 1
```

See running example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe4ad/3

Comment: This was very helpful - thanks!  I didn't know that you could link queries together with "WITH".

Comment: That's called a common table expression or CTE. It isn't required here, I could have written the query like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe4ad/5 but it made the important part clearer.